# Parse JsonArray without key in android

Tags: android, json, arrays

i have a json response but is this standard format?

```
[{"code":"123","rate":"0.1","title":"sss","subtitle":"mmm"},{"code":"456","rate":"0.1","title":"bbb","subtitle":"uuu"}]
```

and how can i pars it in android?

```
new JSONObject(result.toString())
```

throw below exception!

```
06-07 11:45:54.943: W/System.err(10310):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
06-07 11:45:54.943: W/System.err(10310):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
06-07 11:45:54.943: W/System.err(10310):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
```

Comment: yes it's valid you can paste your Json in http://jsonlint.com/ for check validation

Comment: your json is an Array not an object so you need `new JSONArray(result.toString());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i have a json response but is this standard format?

It would be without the `<` at the beginning and the `>` at the end. So:

```
new JSONObject(result.toString().substring(1, result.length() - 2));
```

or more likely:

```
new JSONArray(result.toString().substring(1, result.length() - 2));
```

since the top level of it is an array.

*Since you've removed the `<` and `>` you had originally:*

Since the top level of it is an array, you probably want `JSONArray`, not `JSONObject`:

```
new JSONArray(result.toString());
```

Comment: you are correct.but the problem is not < and >;thanks

Comment: @Mimad: In what way is not those? Those make it invalid JSON, so you can't parse it. Without them, it *is* valid JSON, and you can parse it. (Also: You probably want `new JSONArray` rather than `new JSONObject`, as it's an array, not an object. I've added that.)

Comment: it s my fault in logging!:D

Comment: @Mimad: Ah, okay. So it's just the `JSONObject` vs. `JSONArray` thing.

Answer (score 3):

this is `JSONarray`

```
[{"code":"123","rate":"0.1","title":"sss","subtitle":"mmm"},{"code":"456","rate":"0.1","title":"bbb","subtitle":"uuu"}]
```

try to parse

```
 new JSONArray(result.toString())
```

Answer (score 1):

First assign your json array like this

```
JSONArray jsar=new JSONArray(result);
```

then parse objects like this

```
for(int i=0;i<jsar.length;i++)
{
JSONObject jsobj=new JSONObject(jsar[i]);

String strcode=jsobj.get("code");

String strrate=jsobj.get("rate");

String strtitle=jsobj.get("title");

String strsubtitle=jsobj.get("subtitle");
}
```

hope this will help you,.